# HTTP proxy server for Windows that forwards to SOCKS proxy

Tags: windows, proxy, http, socks

I have am application for Windows which only supports HTTP proxies (no SOCKS support).

Because I already have some good SOCKS proxy lists, I was wondering: Is there some HTTP proxy server for Windows OS, that could "forward" (translate?) connections to SOCKS proxies?

So the connection would look like this:

> App → local HTTP proxy (as "translator" to SOCKS proxies) → SOCKS proxy

Is it possible? Is there such software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Delegate](http://www.delegate.org) as a local http-proxy server, it also supports forwarding to SOCKS proxies.

the usage would be something like :

```
%delegate -P8080 SERVER=http SOCKS=destsocksaddr:port
```

(running http proxy on local port 8080)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to use Delegate on Windows 7.
I have HTTP Proxy in my campus. I am trying to somehow convert the HTTP Proxy to Socks so that i can have UDP connections.
From you reply i find Delegate useful in helping me however i fail to understand how to configure it.
Please Help.

Comment: I'm not sure if what you are looking for is really possible, AFAIK a http proxy only supports http requests