# Is there a SOCKS proxy server program that supports a HTTP parent proxy?

Tags: proxy, http, socks

Is there a SOCKS proxy server program that supports a HTTP parent proxy?

(that is, I am using a program that requires a SOCKS proxy server, but I only have a HTTP proxy server. The SOCKS proxy server would be run on my computer like [Polipo](https://www.irif.fr/%7Ejch/software/polipo/) (which is a HTTP proxy server program that supports a SOCKS parent proxy).)

Comment: . one might be along these lines. These questions ask for http to socks. you want socks to http, but the same program may do it   http://superuser.com/questions/383072/http-proxy-server-for-windows-that-forwards-to-socks-proxy  http://superuser.com/questions/443160/is-there-a-socks-proxy-server-program-that-supports-a-http-parent-proxy    http://www.delegate.org/delegate/    be great to see different solutions to this

Answer (score 1):

You can use some open source software, here is some:

1. using Golang: https://github.com/stdupp/valuga
2. using Python: https://gist.github.com/zengxs/dc6cb4dea4495ecaab7b44abb07a581f
3. using Rust: https://github.com/fokx/sock5_proxy_to_http_proxy_converter