# Debian Linux: How can I expose a SOCKS proxy as a HTTP proxy for the purpose of HTTP/HTTPS requests?

Tags: linux, proxy, socks-proxy, http-proxy, socks

How can I allow a program, which only supports talking through a HTTP proxy, to talk through a SOCKS proxy? In other words, take the HTTP-proxy request and turn it into a SOCKS-proxy request which gets forwarded to the SOCKS proxy, and pass the returned data back to the program through the HTTP proxy.

I need a solution that works on Debian Linux, preferably using software that is prepackaged in Debian's *main* repository.

The chain of communications would be: My program -> HTTP proxy (local) -> SOCKS proxy (local) -> External access

I found a handful of questions about doing it the other way around (a SOCKS proxy forwarding to a HTTP proxy), but that doesn't help me. [HTTP proxy server for Windows that forwards to SOCKS proxy](https://superuser.com/q/383072/53590) is similar to what I want, but since it asks for Windows solutions it doesn't help me.

Comment: You can use `TorSocks` for this. It's a preloadable library that redirects programs to use a socks proxy. It's typically used to redirect to Tor, but it can redirect to anything.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Interesting! It doesn't exactly match the question title, but it does seem to allow me to do what I want to be able to (have the original application talk through a SOCKS proxy). Would you be willing to post that as an answer?

Comment: `DeleGate` is not just for Windows, it exists for all OSes, just look here, ftp://delegate.hpcc.jp/pub/DeleGate/bin/linux/9.9.13/

Comment: [`forward-socks5`](https://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/config.html#SOCKS) of `Privoxy` can also achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TorSocks](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torsocks.git) for this. It's a preloadable library that redirects programs to use a socks proxy. It's typically used to redirect to Tor, but it can redirect to anything.

Comment: `tsocks` IIRC is the program `torsocks` uses or is based on, and can be configured to redirect to anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

`v2ray` and https://github.com/oyyd/http-proxy-to-socks both can do this.

An example of using the latter:

```
npm install -g http-proxy-to-socks
```

Exposes the socks proxy on port `1078` as an HTTP proxy on port `1088`:

```
hpts --level info -s 127.0.0.1:1078 -p 1088
```